# pyspark dataframe to extract each distinct word from a column of string and put them into a new dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to find all strings in a column in pyspark dataframe.

the input df:

```
 id val 
 1  "book bike car"
 15 "car TV bike"
```

I need an output df like: (the word_index value is auto-increment index and the order of values in "val_new" is random.)

```
 val_new word_index
 TV      1
 car     2
 bike    3
 book    4
```

My code :

```
 import pyspark.sql.functions as F
 from pyspark.sql.types import  ArrayType, StringType
 import re

 def my_f(col):
     if not col: 
         return 
     s = ''
     if isinstance(col, str):
         s = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', ' ', col).split()
     return s 

 my_udf = F.udf(my_f, ArrayType(StringType()))

 df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'book bike car'), (18, 'car TV bike')], ['id', 'val'])
 df = df.withColumn('val_new', my_udf(F.col('val')))
```

I have converted the string to array but how to extract the words from each row, remove duplicates, and create a new dataframe with the two new columns ?

I do not want to use groupBy and aggregate because the dataframe may be large and I do not need the "id" column and any duplicates of "val".

thanks

Comment: What exactly is the point of the `word_index` - is it anything special beyond just an auto-increment index?

Comment: @Grismar, it is auto-increment index. thanks

Comment: Your questions seems very similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793412/pyspark-dataframe-get-unique-elements-from-column-with-string-as-list-of-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a working solution for you - use **`spark`** in-build functions instead using a udf , which eventually can make your application slow. The functions
**`explode()`** **`groupBy()`** with **`collect_set()`** will help you achieve the desired result.

## Create the DF Here

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'book bike car'), (18, 'car TV bike')], ['id', 'val'])
df = df.withColumn("dummy_col", F.lit(1))
df.show()
+---+-------------+---------+
| id|          val|dummy_col|
+---+-------------+---------+
|  1|book bike car|        1|
| 18|  car TV bike|        1|
+---+-------------+---------+
```

## Logic Here

```
#Add a dummy column to groupBy & in a single line
df = df.withColumn("array_col", F.split("val", " "))
#Collect_set will return you an array without duplicates
df_grp = df.groupBy("dummy_col").agg(F.collect_set("array_col").alias("array_col"))
#explode to transpoe the column
df_grp = df_grp.withColumn("explode_col", F.explode("array_col"))
df_grp = df_grp.withColumn("explode_col", F.explode("explode_col"))
#Distince to remove the duplicates
df_grp = df_grp.select("explode_col").distinct()
#another dummy column to create the row number
df_grp = df_grp.withColumn("dummy_col", F.lit("A"))
_w = W.partitionBy("dummy_col").orderBy("dummy_col")
df_grp = df_grp.withColumn("rnk", F.row_number().over(_w))
df_grp.show(truncate=False)
```

## Final Output

```
+-----------+---------+---+
|explode_col|dummy_col|rnk|
+-----------+---------+---+
|TV         |A        |1  |
|car        |A        |2  |
|bike       |A        |3  |
|book       |A        |4  |
+-----------+---------+---+
```